# initializing a sub viewmodel from within a viewmodel

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I've got my `IndexViewModel` which sends (currently ) one field to the view

- `List<StaffMemberViewModel> StaffMembers`

The `StaffMemberViewModel` just holds the Full Name of the staff member as well as their CorporateTitle.

All of the Staff data is contained within a JSON file (but could just as easily be in a database).

Here's how I'm currently building the `IndexViewModel`

```
   public class IndexViewModel : LayoutViewModel
    {
        public IndexViewModel()
        {
            // initialize _staffMembers
            _staffMembers = new List<StaffMemberViewModel>();

            var staffModel = new JsonFileReader()
                .GetModelFromFile<List<Staff>>
                (@"~/App_Data/Staff.json");

            foreach (var member in staffModel)
            {
                _staffMembers.Add(new StaffMemberViewModel
                {
                    FullName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", member.FirstName, member.MiddleInitial, member.LastName),
                    CorporateTitle = member.CorporateTitle
                });
            }
        }

        private readonly List<StaffMemberViewModel> _staffMembers;
        public List<StaffMemberViewModel> StaffMembers {get {return _staffMembers;}}
    }

    public class StaffMemberViewModel
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string CorporateTitle { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in the controller I just use something like this.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new IndexViewModel;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

If I want my code to follow [S.O.L.I.D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principals, how could I better wire this up? Keeping in mind that Controllers are supposed to be thin, and therefore I don't want to bloat the controller with the call to the json file. Should I create a service to populate the `StaffMemberViewModel`?

---

*I should also note: the IndexViewModel inherits from an abstract `LayoutViewModel` that contains things like the page title and other reusable properties. For brevity, I didn't show it. I will also be adding more properties to the IndexViewModel, so solving this by removing the IndexViewModel layer and going straight to the `StaffMemberViewModel` is not a valid solution.*

Comment: Mmn.. from the code your Controller isn't doing anything. Your ViewModel is. Which is bad? You probably want to separate that into a Model object. Or Service.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking "service"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like StaffMemberViewModel is, in fact, a model? It is a model that your ViewModel is attempting to display. As for wiring it up, I'd do a little tidying and dependency injection, as well as create a Mapper Factory:

```
public class IndexViewModel : LayoutViewModel
{
    public IndexViewModel(IEnumerable<StaffModel> staffModel)
    {
        _staffMembers = StaffModelMapperFactory.Map(staffModel);
    }

    private readonly List<PartialStaffViewModel> _staffMembers;
    public List<PartialStaffViewModel> StaffMembers {get {return _staffMembers;}}
}
```

```
public class PartialStaffViewModel
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string CorporateTitle { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class StaffModelMapperFactory
{
    public static List<PartialStaffViewModel> Map(IEnumerable<StaffModel> staff)
    {
        return staff.Select(member => new PartialStaffViewModel
            {
                FullName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", member.FirstName, member.MiddleInitial, member.LastName), 
                CorporateTitle = member.CorporateTitle
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var staffModel = new JsonFileService().ReadFileToModel<List<StaffModel>>(@"~/App_Data/Staff.json");

    var model = new IndexViewModel(staffModel)
        {
            Title = "Future State Mobile"
        };

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: +1 I see validity in your answer, but I would clarify that "StaffMemberViewModel" is a valid ViewModel simply because the `Staff` model is the data model.

Comment: I decided to go with a `StaffModelMapperService` to do the mapping. I request the `List<StaffModel>` from within the Controller and pass it to the `IndexViewModel` constructor. In the constructor, I call the Mapper.

Comment: Your `StaffModelMapperService` acts to generate viewmodels from models? In that case, I'd call it something like: `StaffViewModelFactory` I'm not sure about others but `Service` to me involves something like IO or an external entity of some sort.

Comment: For my own projects, I need to create nested controls (think: document hierarchies). The pattern your adapting is only a small step from that kind of generic programming: `public IndexViewModel(IEnumerable<Model>, Func<Model, Control> viewFactory)` etc. etc. Once you get into the hang of dependency injection and functional patterns you can really kick up UI design a gear or two.

Comment: If you update your answer to include `StaffModelMapperFactory` instead of the mapping in the controller, I can definitely accept this answer

Comment: Heh, I'll try and get around to this tomorrow (it's late here and my head is in F# mode)

Comment: Thanks for that Chase. I'd only be able to describe a discriminated union or a bed at this time.